# Move vertices but keep original shape

Tags: uv, vertices

I want to retarget a asset store asset I have for a slightly different use case. So I need to narrow it down a bit but keep the shape of it. If its a straigth shape I can just move the vertices and it would just work. But this is a curved shape. See screenshot. How Can I narrow it down without ruining the shape? Also I need to preserve UV too.

[image]

edit: It seems edge slide is doing just what I want and then check Correct UVs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select all of the horizontal edges (you must be in edge select mode) and then set the pivot point to Individual Origins you can scale just the edges that control the with of your object.

Another option is to double tap G and slide each outer edge loop towards the center.